# Week month and 6mo view toggle on one graph

Tags: javascript, chart.js

My current code

```
 // Reporting line chart
          var reportingLineChartCanvas = document.getElementById("reporting-lineChart");
          currentVue.reportingLineChart = new Chart(reportingLineChartCanvas, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
              labels: [],
              datasets: []
            },
            options: {
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              responsive: true,
              maintainAspectRatio: true,
              legend: {
                display: false
              }
            }
          });
```

[current line chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfv5D.png)

I would like the line chart to show data from one week by default and give the user the ability to toggle between week, month, and 6mo time frames. Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please have a look at the following Chart.js sample and view the page source: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/time/financial.html

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I was missing!